# Angular 2: How do I exclude navbar from a page?

Tags: angular

In app.component.html, I include the navbar in every page by doing this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

How do I exclude the navbar from a given page?

Comment: You can include `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` into every component's HTML, where you need it, and just don't include where it's not necessary.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Not at all. Hope it's really helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the nature of Angular as being a single page application so if you put your router outlet in the app component HTML alongside with the `<navbar></navbar>` the navbar will always be visible.

So how do you hide it when you navigate to certain pages and show it to the others? You simply use *ngIf with `showNav` being a variable holding a boolean value (true or false) you define it in the component typescript file and you change it depending on the current navigated route using some help from built-in router form `@angular/router`.

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="showNav"></app-navbar>
```